# How to slow down my Variable Timestep Loop in Java

Tags: game-loop

I am currently developing a game in Java and I ran into a problem

At first, I thought my game loop was working well as it was giving a similar amount of FPS as the tutorial I was following

Then I reach to the phase where I started implementing input from the user. When the user entered in the W key the sprite would move very rapidly to the bottom of the screen and then back up to the top for no explained reason

I think it is something to do with my game loop. As I did my research I deduced that my game loop is running way to fast. The only problem is that I haven't been able to slow down the loop. Or maybe it is a totally different problem

Can anyone please help

Run method of my game:

```
public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0 ;

    /*  Game loop use:
     *      From timer calls to while loops to recursive function calls to keep the game alive 
     *      Until a certain condition is meet (The loop)
     * 
     *      A way to delay the length of each loop iteration so you get a stable frame rate (The timing mechanism) 
     *  
     *      A way to make the game speed remain independent of the speed of the loop (The interpolation)*/

    //This is a variable timestep loop
    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1) {
            tick();
            delta--;
        }
        if(running)
            render();
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
            frames = 0;
            //While times updated per second is greater than one (allowing updates to be seen) call tick method of Handler class


            /* Fixed timestep loops vs Variable timestep loops:
             * 
             *      Variable timestep loops: Great because the game will seem consistent regardless of how fast the players's computer is
             *          Allowing it to work on a variety of machines and update the game logic with very high attention to details happening in the game 
             *          Graphics latency is not a problem as things are drawn as they change
             * 
             *      
             *    
             *      Fixed timestep loops: You know that every single timestep 
             *          will take up the exact same length of time. Allows for consistent gameplay 
             *          regardless of how fast a machine is as you know the tick rate of your machine
             *          Works wonderfully for math-heavy games with physics operations. Also good for networked games as packets are going and coming at a generally constant speed.
             *          Keeps game logic running at a very low rate while the frame rate can still and frame rate really high 
             *                                                            */
        }
        stop();
    }
}
```

'''

Thanks!!!

Comment: This looks like a fixed timestep to me, not a variable timestep; for a variable timestep, you would need to pass down deltaTme to each of your method (starting with tick()), here it looks like you assume it's 1/60th of a second. Like it's being mentioned in the answer: we would need to know your movement code to help you further.

Comment: I was able to figure it out but thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

A game loop is *meant* to run as fast as it can -  whether 30 fps or 1000fps. So your loop code is fine.

The problem is that your move function is meant to run only on that frame where the key *goes* down, not on every single frame where the key *is* down (which, even if you tapped the key very lightly, would typically still be several frames, meaning several moves would be made, in very quick succession).

Since you don't share your input function, I cannot advise directly, but most frameworks have `onKeyDown` vs `isKeyDown` (names may differ) functionality for you to choose between. `onKeyDown` is typically an event handler that will only fire **once** - on that frame where the key first goes down.